# Secular schools in Dubai

Tags: education, religion

I got a contract opportunity to work in Dubai, and considering it. Are there good private schools that teach in German or English, that don't compel students to learn about Islam (besides basic general knowledge about culture and history), or worse - compel them to pray or something?

I've read that private schools are under some level of control, and given that it's such a theocratic state, I'm wondering if it's possible to raise a secular family there.

Comment: Any international school ought to be fine, of which there are many!

Comment: There are many international schools like [this](http://www.dubaibritishschool.ae/). In fact you'll be surprised how much theocratic is Dubai :)  Besides, I do not think that a little knowledge about the country culture that you and your kids grow up in will harm.